# VBA Excel, changing an ActiveX toggle button's state

Tags: vba, activex, togglebutton

i'm having an issue with an ActiveX toggle button. I would like to be able to change its state (pushed or not) depending on a cell property.

I am trying to use the ControlFormat to access the Value property of the button like this:

```
Sheets("activity_tracking").Shapes("lock_unlock_curr_row").ControlFormat.Value = True
```

But i get error 438: "Object doesn't support this property or method". This is puzzling for me because ".ControlFormat.Enabled = True" works for this button.

I would be grateful for any insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the name of your ActiveX toggle button is `lock_unlock_curr_row` then consider

```
Sheets("activity_tracking").lock_unlock_curr_row.Value = True
```